# How to get subdirectory from the FTP server?

Tags: iphone, ftp

I have implemented one application in which the user can connect with FTP server from the iphone using authentication, and get the listing of the directory.

Now when user touch on main directory then I want subdirectory listing.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take a look at the following link and framework that deal with FTP sessions and downloading/uploading, and listing/creating directories.

iPhone FTP Example that deals with listing/creating FTP directories

- [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/index.html)

Simple FTP component for iPhone apps (inspired from the idea of [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/))

- [s7ftprequest](http://code.google.com/p/s7ftprequest/)

With these two references you should be well on your way to getting your directory listing from a FTP server. Hope this info helps. Post a comment if need any additional help.